# How to install qtip2 for tooltip using npm in angular 2 application?

Tags: jquery, angular, npm, installation, qtip2

I am trying to install qtip2 in my angular2 app, but everytime I do, it shows errors [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oqhmc.png)

I searched in google and could not find any solution on how to install qtip2 JQuery plugin using npm for tooltips.

I tried to update the JQuery with version 2.0.3 as the error shows and updated npm too  but still nothing helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try first:

1:

```
npm install jsdom
```

2:

```
npm install jquery
```

3:

```
npm install qtip2
```

In `package.json` you will have these dependencies ... and others

```
"dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jsdom": "^11.3.0"
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]